# How to load HTML string as an ExtJS object/element to use selectors

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am using **ExtJS 4.2.0** and I was wondering if it's possible to load an **HTML string** to get  an **ExtJS** `object/element` in order to use `selectors`.

In order to be more specific, I will put the following code snippet to understand the situation:

(I am using **jQuery** since I am more familiar with it and the code is still understandable to show what I'm trying to do with **ExtJS**).

```
var html = '<div id="wrapper">' +
    '<div class="sub">One</div>' +
    '<div class="sub">Two</div>' +
    '<div class="sub">Three</div>' +
    '</div>';

var elems = $(html).find('.sub');
console.log(elems);
```

In the above code snippet, I am loading the **HTML string** as a **jQuery** `object` by doing `$(html)` and then using `selectors` by getting all elements that are using `.sub` **CSS class**.

However, I've tried the following to replicate the same with **ExtJS** by using `Ext.DomHelper` without success.

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uaBj4/

```
var obj = Ext.DomHelper.createDom(html);
var arr = Ext.select('.sub', obj);
console.log(arr.elements);
```

And I was searching over the internet but in many examples they use a `listener` which affects a `component` that was already created and then grab the `dom` element or, in other cases, they use `Ext.fly(..)` or `Ext.select(..)` to manipulate an element that already exists in `dom` which is not my case or what I'm trying to do.

---

**Update:** I noticed that I was using `Ext.select(..)` the wrong way! (like old `ExtJS`  versions). Check API docs for **ExtJS 4.2.0**: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext-method-select. Then I just got my `obj` variable and don't know what more to do.

Comment: maybe extjs doesn't provide any simple tools. you can do var d=document.createElement("div"); d.innerHTML=html; instead of $(html)

Comment: @dandavis I'm not sure about it, that's why I am asking. Using simple `javascript` will be my last resource.

Comment: well, search around for "dom element from string" tools

Comment: Although it is possible and easy to manipulate DOM by Ext, I usually do not need to think html. I think higher level components: toolbar, button, menu, window, etc. - the html Ext produces is not interesting. What exactly do you want to achieve? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: @Saki This is what I got: I make an `ajax` call to a `rest` service which returns `XML` or `JSON`. Then I `unmarshal` the response using `ExtJS`, after that I use `Ext.String.htmlDecode` to retrieve `HTML`  entities from the response. Finally, I pass the `HTML` to a panel component (by using `html` property).

Comment: Json returned from the server contains some data, right? If so then use this data and pass it to XTemplate to generate the resulting html. Easy, clean, straightforward. BTW, can you post the returned json?

Comment: @Saki But the issue is that `HTML` response comes from server with a predefined style (not using `CSS` classes, they are using `style` property for some elements or `font` tags to apply some `background`, `font-color`, etc). However, I can't modify server side so I my idea was to have the `response` and `override` some elements by using selectors and apply `CSS` classes to them (like my `jQuery` example). My other idea was to use an `Ext.Template` (but first I want to achieve the same as I do with `jQuery` - also caught my attention if it was possible or not).

Comment: @Saki By now, I've added a listener to that panel (before getting displayed in the UI) so inside that handler I got the panel object and from that I can grab a `dom` object - the one I am requesting on my question but loaded from a `HTML` string. Then I am doing my customizations (I know `Ext.Template` is cleaner but I can figure out why `ExtJS` can't do the same as `jQuery` - I think `ExtJS` is more powerful right? that's all).

Comment: I see, it explains why you need it. Now, did you realize that `DomHelper.createDom` creates the elements **without** appending them to the DOM? That is probably the reason why subsequent `select` does not find them. Append it to its final place in DOM and use `select` afterwards.

Comment: @Saki Yes, I know that but I was wondering to have just an `object` and not append it to the `dom` (like `jQuery` does) also I was using `Ext.select` the wrong way (check arguments for **ExtJS 4.2.0** API). Btw, If you provide a good alternative I can update my question and accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it using the following approach.

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/n36d2/

```
// Sample html string
var html = '<ul id="list">' +
    '<li>One</li>' +
    '<li>Two</li>' +
    '<li>Three</li>' +
    '</ul>';

// Create wrapper html element
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
// Add html string as 'innerHTML'
wrapper.innerHTML = html;
// Create 'dom' element
var dom = Ext.fly(wrapper);
// Use selector in 'dom' element
var li = dom.select('#list > li');
// Print all 'li' elements
console.log(li.elements);
```